# How to solve GraphQL circular references?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I'm trying to separate out my types into individual files. By doing so I've found that any type definition that references the usertype I get the below error. 
User:

```
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLBoolean,
  GraphQLID,
} = require("graphql");

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "User",
  fields: () => ({
    _id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    password: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    active: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    emailConfirmed: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    licenses: {
      type: new GraphQLList(LicenseType),
      async resolve(parent, args) {
        return await LicenseController.getUserLicenses({ id: parent._id });
      },
    },
    services: {
      type: new GraphQLList(ServiceType),
      async resolve(parent, args) {
        return await ServiceController.getUserServices({ id: parent._id });
      },
    },
  }),
});

const LicenseType = require("../types/licenseType");
const ServiceType = require("../types/serviceType");

const LicenseController = require("../../controllers/licenseController");
const ServiceController = require("../../controllers/serviceController");

module.exports = UserType;
```

License:

```
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLBoolean,
  GraphQLID,
} = require("graphql");

const UserType = require("../types/userType");
const UserController = require("../../controllers/userController");

const LicenseType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "License",
  fields: () => ({
    _id: { type: GraphQLID },
    token: { type: GraphQLString },
    creationDate: { type: GraphQLString },
    expirationDate: { type: GraphQLString },
    btcAddress: { type: GraphQLString },
    sessions: { type: GraphQLInt },
    active: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    user_id: { type: GraphQLID },
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      async resolve(parent, args) {
        return await UserController.getSingleUser({ id: parent.user_id });
      },
    },
  }),
});

module.exports = LicenseType;
```

Error:

```
Error: One of the provided types for building the Schema is missing a name.
```

I've tried moving the type/controller definitions above and below the type definitions with no change. How would I provide the user data from the license type?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `require` calls inside the `fields` function -- this way they will not be evaluated until the function is actually called when your schema is constructed.

```
const LicenseType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "License",
  fields: () => {
    const UserType = require("../types/userType");
    const UserController = require("../../controllers/userController");

    return {
      _id: { type: GraphQLID },
      token: { type: GraphQLString },
      creationDate: { type: GraphQLString },
      expirationDate: { type: GraphQLString },
      btcAddress: { type: GraphQLString },
      sessions: { type: GraphQLInt },
      active: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
      user_id: { type: GraphQLID },
      user: {
        type: UserType,
        async resolve(parent, args) {
          return await UserController.getSingleUser({ id: parent.user_id });
        },
      },
    }
  },
});
```